# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SearchToners'. Pero el DropDownList NO ESTA dentro del Form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

**Tengo este formulario:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Equipments", FormMethod.Post, new { }))
                    {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Parts)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Toners)
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SerialNumber)
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SerialNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Entre serial del equipo", required = "required" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypeMachine)
                        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.TypeMachine, "Seleccione...", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model)
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Model, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Entre modelo del equipo", required = "required" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location)
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Entre ubicación del equipo", required = "required" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IP)
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
                            </div>
                            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="Debe ser una dirección IP válida" data-val-length-max="12" data-val-length-min="4" data-val-regex="Debe ser una dirección IP válida" data-val-regex-pattern="^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$" data-val-required="Dirección IP requerida" id="IP" name="IP" placeholder="172.239.17.192" type="text" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PMInterval)
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PMInterval, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "60,000", required = "required" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CounterBnWCopies)
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CounterBnWCopies, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "60,000", required = "required" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CounterBnWPrints)
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CounterBnWPrints, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "60,000", required = "required" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CounterColorCopies)
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CounterColorCopies, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "60,000", required = "required" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CounterColorPrints)
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CounterColorPrints, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "60,000", required = "required" } })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="IsActive" id="IsActive" data-val="true" data-val-required="El campo Disponible / Activo es obligatorio." style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
                            <label for="IsActive"> Disponible / Activo</label>
                        </div>
                        <p class="help-block">Este Equipo estará disponible?</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-footer">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Crear">
                </div>
            }
```

**y tambien, este elemento:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("SearchToners", ViewBag.SearchToners as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Buscar Toners para modelo", new { @class = "form-control selectpicker", style = "width:270px" })
```

**Metodo en el controller**

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.BreadCrumb = new List<string> { "Stock", "Equipos", "Crear" };
        ViewBag.SearchToners = new SelectList(EquipmentService.ToList().ToList(), "Id", "Model");
        return View();
    }
```

El DropDownList esta fuera y muy lejos del Form. No se por que me da ese error si ni siquiera esta dentro de request que se enviara al controlador

Answer (score 0):

**[SOLUCIONADO]**

En el método post estoy retornando la vista sin mas. Entonces ASP, inteligentemente, lee la vista a la cual sera direccionada la respuesta del servidor.

Cuando ASP intentaba dibujar el DropDownList no encontraba el ViewBag.SearchToner. 
No existe, por que nunca se creo, en esa respuesta del servidor.

Metodos:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.SearchToners = new SelectList(EquipmentService.ToList().ToList(), "Id", "Model");
        return View();
    }
```

Antes de la solucion:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(string test)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Después de la solución:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(string test)
    {
        ViewBag.SearchToners = new SelectList(EquipmentService.ToList().ToList(), "Id", "Model");
        return View();
    }
```